# react-grid-layout (ResponsiveGridLayout) initial rendering issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, react-grid-layout

I am using react-grid-layout to integrate the drag and drop for my app. However, the expected behavior is to have the items in a linear manner. Instead whenever I load the app it is showing me all the items stacked on the first column. However, when I re-render it without making any changes, it shows me everything in a linear manner as expected.
initial load -
[initial load -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdCMT.png)

[re-rendered load-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IvoF.png)

[react grid layout-](https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout)

tried adding a the width prop from the grid-layout but doesn't seem to solve the problem.

code-

```
    function generateLayout() {
     return nodes.map(function (item, i) {
      const y = 2;
      return {
       x: i % 8,
       y: Math.floor(i / 6),
       w: 1,
       h: 1,
       i: item.id,
        };
      });
     }

    function generateWidgets() {
      return _.map(_.range(20), function(i) {
      return (
         <div key={i}>
          <span className="text">{i}</span>
         </div>
        );
       });
     }

    return(
    <ResponsiveGridLayout
      isDraggable={true}
      rowHeight={350}
      cols={{lg: 3, md: 3, sm: 3, xs: 2, xxs: 1}}
      breakpoints={{lg: 1350, md: 1150, sm: 768, xs: 480, xxs: 0}}>
      {generateWidgets()}
    </ResponsiveGridLayout>
   )
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: just updated with the code.